# Change title text to an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change the following text logo into a logo, currently used by a theme on WordPress.

It looks like this now:

[image]

My logo is currently on the server at: `content/uploads/2016/07/cropped-Site_Logo-1.png`

```
<div id="ribbon" class="span12 center none">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="text_logo"><a href="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cropped-Site_Logo-1.png">StrtUp</a></h1>
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile_menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `change it into a logo`?

Comment: Snipping Tool is your friend.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking

Comment: it depends on your current theme source code, maybe there is some parameter you can set when customizing your theme, please have a check in Wordpress backend theme pages, from here we can't do anything

Answer (score 1):

If you do not intend to make the site logo changeable, it's probably better moving it to your theme folder (under a `images` folder, for example) and use:

```
<h1 class="text_logo">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/cropped-Site_Logo-1.png" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

If you do intend to make it changeable, in WP 4.5 you can use [`custom_logo` feature](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/10/custom-logo/), adding it to your functions.php:

```
function theme_prefix_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_prefix_setup' );
```

And change your code to:

```
<h1 class="text_logo">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>"><?php the_custom_logo() ?></a>
</h1>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked like a bomb, Thanks dude

Comment: Nice @zanderlabuschagne! Consider upvoting and/or accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 class="text_logo">
  <a href="/">
   <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cropped-Site_Logo-1.png" />
  </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Also Worked Thanks dude